# Unable to login to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, azure, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

Im trying to connect to my windows azure sql database using SQL server authentication but this is the error that appears

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

I have checked and my server name, username and password are all correct. Does anyone have an explanation to this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend here you go: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Comment: Thanks for your help hermann. This article was really good but however even after following all the steps i am still getting the error. Would you know of any other way this error could be solved?